# is dp really device independent?

Tags: android, android-layout

This sounds stupid , but I have confusion. 
I have defined a  layout which have a stripe of images . Strip height is set as some x dp. But 
I can see difference in height , in difference phones (in samsung note2 it looks bigger than nexus 4). Can someone explain or provide some useful links ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 3):

FYI, DP stands for **Density independent pixel**.

And Here is definition of Screen density:

> **Screen density**
>
> The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the
>   screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a
>   "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area,
>   compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have read there ,according to it x dp should look of same size independent of screen density and size. but what I have observed is different . I can see size difference in difference screen size phones.

Comment: @user1875798 you have observed it right, but button/image with 1 dp will be looking different because 1 dp measurement will be done based on the density of the particular device. If its ldpi then your 1 dp button will look small and if its hdpi screen then it will superb.

Comment: 1dp can have different number of pixels based on device density means a device 1dp can have x pixels and another can have y pixels but size should appear same that is what I have understood from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. so ideally device is ldpi or hdpi should not matter , correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user1875798 At one side you are saying *different pixels in different devices* and at another side you are saying it should be same, how strange !!

Comment: what I know is 1 dp is equivalent to 1 pixel size in a 160 dpi device. After that If dpi differs you can cal pixels in dp but size remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

These may help:

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

The mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, ... suffixes stands for **generalized** densities.

That means that 2 xhdpi phones might have slightly different real densities.

For example, Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy SIII are both noted as xhdpi, but Galaxy Nexus has a 316ppi screen, whereas Galaxy SIII screen is a 306ppi

source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung)

Comment: I agree that both can have different density but If I am defining size in dp in that case density should not matter. Correct me If I am wrong.