# how to using android dp unit correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

A 100 dp button is looking of different size in Nexus 4 and Samsung Note II. 
But according to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence the size on both the phone should appear the same. 
What am I missing?

Comment: post what you have done. a screen shot should give a better idea

Comment: Try using sp instead of dp. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android/2025541#2025541). Hope this help.

Comment: They should appear to take up the same "Relative" space on the screen not the same pixel count.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879077/is-dp-really-device-independent/15879150#15879150